# Count the number of times the link is clicked (ASP.NET Core razor page asp-page-handler)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Who can help me? I have a link that points to another page. And
I want to count the number of times this link is clicked and store it
in my SQL Server database. My page is an ASP.NET Core razor page. I
have a column `variabelSearch` in my database table and I have to increase this column by +1 every time I click on the link.

```
Public void OnGetLeagueAsync(Guid? varLgPlayerId)
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("SessionLgPlayerId", varLgPlayerId.ToString());
    Response.Redirect("/LeaguePlayerDetails"); 

    variabelSearch++;
}

<td>
    <a asp-page-handler="League" asp-route-varLgPlayerId="@itemP.id">@itemP.naam</a>
</td>
```

Comment: When asking questions about communicating with databases, you should mention the data access technology you are using - EF Core, Dapper, ADO.NET... But this type of question is probably most suited to [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/), where you can get an instant answer and explanation.

Comment: Hi @New' asp.net core' One, any update here?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need have a table which contains property `variabelSearch`:

```
public class SearchCount
{
    // Other properties...
    public int VariabelSearch { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your backend code:

```
public async Task OnGetLeagueAsync(Guid? varLgPlayerId)
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("SessionLgPlayerId", varLgPlayerId.ToString());

    // Assuming _context is your database context, 
    //and you have a known ID for the row you're updating. e.g. your passing varLgPlayerId
    var searchCount = await _context.SearchCounts.FindAsync(knownId);
    if (searchCount != null)
    {
        searchCount.VariabelSearch += 1;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    Response.Redirect("/LeaguePlayerDetails");
}
```